# How to turn off single user mode on a remote machine?

Tags: linux, init, remote-management

I have a linux machine that I was accessing remotely and I made the mistake of doing `#init 1` which turned off networking on the machine.

What is the easiest way to turn networking back on and/or get the machine out of single user mode?

I do have personnel that can access the machine locally if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the remote hands to get into the system via the console and run `telinit 3` or `telinit 5` if either of those were the runlevels you were using previously.

Comment: Ah thank you very much, do you know if just rebooting the machine will turn off single user mode or must `telinit #` command be run?

Comment: @Quinma It should boot back into what ever run level is specified in your grub config http://www.brunolinux.com/05-Configuring_Your_System/Grub_boot_runlevel-3.html

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options

**Change run level**

type in `runlevel`. It will show the current and the former run levels. Your's probably looks like this:

```
$ runlevel  
3 1
```

(1 is your current level, and 3 is your previous run level)
The person at the site can then run the following

`telinit 3`

**Reboot**

Gracefully bounce the server. The run level will return to what ever is configured in your grub config. 
http://www.centos.org/docs/4/html/rhel-rg-en-4/s1-grub-runlevels.html

---

**Fun Fact**

On most recent linux distros, `telinit` is a symbolic link that points to `init`. You can save 3 letters by typing the shorter `init`.